# Pass Parameters To Method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, parameter-passing

I am getting an error of

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'b2' of 'Form1.checkInfo(PointF, PointF, PointF, PointF, ref PointF)'  WindowsFormsApplication1

when I attempt to pass parameters to a method.  This is my syntax, and to me it looks like `b2` is declared, and assigned and being passed, but I can not discover what I need to change to make the error go away!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point[] points = new Point[] { new Point { X = -100, Y = 0 }, new Point { X = 0, Y = 0 } };
    PointF returnedPoint = new PointF();
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Count(); i++)
    {
        float X1value = points[i].X;
        float X2value = points[i-1].X;
        float Y1value = points[i].Y;
        float Y2value = points[i-1].Y;
        checkInfo(new PointF(X1value, Y1value), new PointF(X2value, Y2value), ref returnedPoint);
    }
}
bool checkInfo(PointF a1, PointF a2, PointF b1, PointF b2, ref PointF returnedPoint)
{
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Well yes - you're trying to pass *two* `Point` values by value followed by one by reference, and the method has *four* `Point` parameters passed by value followed by one by reference. How do you expect that to work? What do you expect `checkInfo` to do with only half the information it's asking for?

Comment: @JonSkeet - in my head what is taking place is I am passing in two PointF and in the method I am receiving PointF a1 which is X1Value, a2 which is Y1value, b1 which is X2value, and b2 which is Y2value then the parameter by ref.  So everything aligns?

Comment: A point is an X value *and* a Y value, not just one. It sounds like you should just have `PointF a, PointF b`... or change the parameters to `float ax, float ay, float bx, float by` and pass `X1value, Y1value, X2value, Y2value`. You need to think more clearly about the difference between a point and just an X value or a Y value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'b2' of 'Form1.checkInfo(PointF, PointF,
>   PointF, PointF, ref PointF)' WindowsFormsApplication1

Your method `checkInfo(PointF a1, PointF a2, PointF b1, PointF b2, ref PointF returnedPoint)` takes 5 parameters, but you call it `checkInfo(new PointF(X1value, Y1value), new PointF(X2value, Y2value), ref returnedPoint)` with only 3 parameters. The error message complains about missing parameters.
 
Please see my comments below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point[] points = new Point[] { new Point { X = -100, Y = 0 }, new Point { X = 0, Y = 0 } };
    PointF returnedPoint = new PointF();
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Count(); i++)
    {
        float X1value = points[i].X;
        float X2value = points[i-1].X;
        float Y1value = points[i].Y;
        float Y2value = points[i-1].Y;

        // Error located here: Only 3 parameters passed - You need to pass 2 more instances of 'PointF'
        checkInfo(new PointF(X1value, Y1value), new PointF(X2value, Y2value), ref returnedPoint);
    }
}

// Takes 5 parameters 
bool checkInfo(PointF a1, PointF a2, PointF b1, PointF b2, ref PointF returnedPoint)
{
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: AH - I thought that the receiving method parsed out the PointF() into individual PointF - that makes sense.